# Heroku keep using gmail as my smtp server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, smtp

i used to have gmail_smtp plugin in my rails application. and nearly time , i change to mandrill. however the heroku still keeps using gmail and search my gmail username and password. Does anybody know how to change that in heroku ? it is really annoying for me.

thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you specifying GMail in an initializer or environment file? What occurrences of `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` are in your source tree?

Comment: Heroku will only do what you tell them to do...especially when it comes to sending email.

Comment: the funny thing is , i can send email via mandrill from my localhost computer but when i push to heroku. it just keep search the gmail smtp. is there any way to check if the gmail_smtp still in my heroku account? thanks a lot!

Comment: @willglynn , no i dont specifiy any gmail setting in the environment. purely mandrill settings in ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings.

Comment: fixed the problem. I need to delete the app in heroku and reinstall it and it uses mandrill only.. dont know if because of the cache problem.